# Network teaming Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, bonding, 10gbethernet

I have two Windows Server 2008 R2 servers that need to share files on SAS attached logical drives over a 10G network connection.

The servers have two 10G ports so I'm wondering if I can use both of them to increase file I/O performance and how it would be done.

Currently I am getting 300Mb/sec file transfer and would like to see 500 to 600Mb/sec.

Comment: How do you know that the network is the bottleneck?

Comment: File transfer from one logical drive to another directly attached to a server is twice as fast as file transfer over the network.

Comment: Well, you aren't saturating the 10G port, so that's the problem you should work on.

Comment: Maybe it's SMB. I need to do some testing. I have not changed any settings yet.

Comment: Update to Windows 2012 R2 (SMBv3), make sure you have Jumbo Frames enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to upgrade.  You'll get the best performance from SMB 3 cluster and clients (ver. 8 and up) but on SMB 2 clients you can at least maximize their nice thruput by enabling jumbo frames on the server.  Note that a CAFS requires an 8 or better client